# NameError: name 'views' is not defined in django 2.2.3 & python 3.7.0

Tags: python, django

I'm doing login and signup in Django but I'm getting the following error. Please help me in solving it.

**File "/home/mritunjay/project/pr/fitbit/accounts/urls.py", line 7, in 
path('', views.home, name="home"),
NameError: name 'views' is not defined**

Here **urls.py (app)**

```
from django.urls import path

from accounts.views import home, SignUpView

app_name = "accounts"


urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('signup/', SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    
]
```

Here **views.py** (app)

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from django.views.generic import CreateView

from accounts.forms import SignUpForm

from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SignUpView(CreateView):

    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    template_name = 'templates/signup.html'

def home(request):

    return render(request, "home.html", {})
```

Here **urls.py** (project)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from django.views.generic import TemplateView

#from accounts import urls

urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),

    # Main Page

    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),

    # Login and Logout

    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True, template_name='templates/login.html'), name='login'),

    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='home'), name='logout'),
]
```

These are code where **NameError: name 'views' is not defined
** is showing in **urls.py(app)**

Please help me in this.

Comment: add `from . import views` in `urls.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are refering views without importing it. Try this in **urls.py (app)**

```
from django.urls import path

from accounts import views

app_name = "accounts"


urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('signup/', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    
]
```

Note: Ensure that `login` function is defined in the `views`.